Django and Firebird
Has anybody a running system using Django and Firebird?
I have installed all development tools as recommended. Currently I am back to python:latest (3.13.0) and installed django (5.1.13). I also use firebird 4.0 database.
I have loaded firebird-driver for python and django-firebird package in the latest version.
If I start a new django project and a new django app without any specific content and also have the following entry in settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'firebird',
        'NAME': '/firebird/data/employee.fdb',
        'USER': 'sysdba',
        'PASSWORD': 'masterkey',
        'HOST': '172.12.0.3',
        'PORT': '3050',
    }
}

I receive the message, that firebird.base has no property "DatabaseWrapper". However the base.py file does provide a property for DatabaseWrapper. Therefore my assumption is, that my configuration described above is not compatible. My question is, can somebody recommend a configuration of python and django that is compatible with the firebird database?
